# Transform skew an object based on screen proportions purely in CSS

Tags: html, css

Using Javascript this would be trivial but I'm wondering if this could be implemented purely in CSS.

For instance if the screen height is 100px and screen width is 100px then transform: skew(0deg).

If screen height is 50px and screen width is 100px then transform: skew(50deg).

Note that I am not looking for media queries because using those I can only make rules for a finite number of screen proportions, I would instead like the skew to change in proportion to the screen width and height.

Comment: `...finite number of screen proportions.` Generate them in script server-side in discrete intervals.

Comment: So you're suggesting I should write a script that writes a css file with thousands of media quarry lines in it? Not the ideal solution for me.